# How would one get OS, Computer Processor Information, total RAM, RAM in use, etc etc in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

I would use ManagementObjectSearcher, but that doesn't seem to be present in .Net Core. How would one go about getting system information such as those in the title using C# with .Net Core?

Comment: `ManagementObjectSearcher` uses WMI which is specifically Windows. As .NET Core is cross platform there is no such API. You're probably going to need a third-party API to get this info.

Comment: This is slated for a [future release](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9376). .Net Core doesn't currently implement this.

Comment: So there's no way I can get "hardware" information in .NET Core right now?

Comment: I've been putting some time into implementing this for macOS and Linux as a .NET Standard 2.0 library. https://github.com/NickStrupat/ComputerInfo

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is what I do. Not my happiest solution but it beats nothing. :) I add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll the project. Between that and Environment, I get:

```
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo computerInfo = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.ProcessorCount);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.AvailablePhysicalMemory);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.AvailableVirtualMemory);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.OSFullName);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.OSPlatform);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.OSVersion);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory);
        Console.WriteLine(computerInfo.TotalVirtualMemory);
```

Comment: If you're adding reference from the full .NET Framework, it won't run on environment where only .NET Core is available